# jquery slider not working from second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, slider

> below is the function for capture the slider value

```
$(function () {
            $('#divslider').slider({
                max: 100,
                min: 0,
                value: 0,
                slide: function (e, ui) {
                    $(this).next().next().val(ui.value);
                    if (ui.value != '') {
                        $(this).parents('.tblQuestion').removeClass('mandatory');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

> below is .aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPercenatage" runat="server" Visible="true">
                                            <div style="width: 40%; background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187)" id="divslider"></div>
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSlider" CssClass="slidevalue" AutoPostBack="false" Width="30px" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>%</span>
                                        </asp:Panel>
```

[image]

slider   appending for first element only

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one slider, you should use classes to select elements.

```
 $('.sliders').slider({...});

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlPercenatage" runat="server" Visible="true">
     <div style="width: 40%; background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187)" id="divslider" class="sliders"></div><br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtSlider" CssClass="slidevalue " AutoPostBack="false" Width="30px" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>%</span>
 </asp:Panel>
....
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPercenatage2" runat="server" Visible="true">
     <div style="width: 40%; background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187)" id="divslider2" class="sliders"></div><br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtSlider2" CssClass="slidevalue" AutoPostBack="false" Width="30px" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>%</span>
 </asp:Panel>
```

However, provide some more sample code representing your situation would help. (your code show us only one slider, image show three)